# BRACE (browserify compatible version of ace-editor) scroll event triggers explosion of "Unable to preventDefault..passive event..." console errors

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

My app implements a custom mode of ACE Editor lib using Brace (a browserify compatible version of the ace editor).

I have found that when scrolling the ace-editor window, the console throws errors of:

"Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation"

They point to this line inside the index.js of the brace source code in node_modules:

```
exports.preventDefault = function(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault(); // <<<< ERROR
    else
        e.returnValue = false;
};
```

Is it possible to prevent this error from triggering within my typescript code where I instantiate the ace-editor instance?

```
 <div
    ace-editor
    *ngIf="formDefinitionPanel.expanded"
    [text]="formDefinitionJSON$ | async"
    [options]="aceEditorOptions"
    [readOnly]="true"
    [autoUpdateContent]="true"
    (textChanged)="updateFormFromEditor($event)"
    class="ace-editor-container"
  ></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brace uses a very old version of ace. This issue is fixed in the current version. You can use ace-builds npm module which is compatible with webpack/browserify as well.

Comment: Thanks but can you clarify what version is the latest? I'm using 0.11.1 which npmjs.com lists as the "latest" but its 5 years old! https://www.npmjs.com/package/brace

Comment: Oh, I suppose you mean ace editor current version (not brace current version), right?

Comment: yes, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ace-builds